# Java Eclipse: ComboBox action button based on item selected (e.g., temperature conversion)

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I am new to Java, and currently using Java Eclipse for practicing. I am having some trouble with comboBox where I am not sure how to go about making the program do something depending on the items selected from two comboboxes. I have two comboBoxes for converting temperature (Celsius, Fahrenheit, kelvin), and I managed to add these items. I am stuck on the convert button. My intention is if combobox1 = Celsius, and combobox2 = Fahrenheit, then use this calculation and output to textField_1 as a Fahrenheit value. Could you help me explicitly how to do this please?  Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!  I have tried searching for something similar, but I couldn't find one that is like mine, and others used netbeans and were quite different.

```
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Convert");//converts temperature input to output based on the comboBox and comboBox1 selections. 
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


            String inputTemp = (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            String inputTemp1 = (String)comboBox_1.getSelectedItem();

            double inputTemp, inputTemp1, Celsius, Fahrenheit, Kelvin;
            inputTemp=Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());

            if (inputTemp.equals("Celsius") && inputTemp1.equals("Fahrenheit")) {
                Celsius = inputTemp;
            Fahrenheit = (Celsius*1.8)+32;
            textField_1.setText(Double.toString(Fahrenheit));

        }else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid value.");
            }

        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    btnNewButton.setBounds(335, 64, 89, 103);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setBounds(41, 129, 147, 38);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);

    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.setBounds(198, 67, 127, 38);
    frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);

    comboBox.addItem("Celsius");
    comboBox.addItem("Fahrenheit");
    comboBox.addItem("Kelvin");

    JComboBox comboBox_1 = new JComboBox();
    comboBox_1.setBounds(198, 129, 127, 38);
    frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox_1);

    comboBox_1.addItem("Celsius");
    comboBox_1.addItem("Fahrenheit");
    comboBox_1.addItem("Kelvin");
```

Comment: A quick glance over the code seems to suggest you're heading in the right direction, what seems to be the issues you're having?

Comment: Try this [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html).

Comment: To MadProgrammer. I entered a value in textfield, then selected my combobox to "Celsius" and combobox1 to "Fahrenheit" then clicked my convert button, nothing happens, except the console's error message comes up "Unresolved compilation problems (exception in thread AWT eventQueue.  My program recognized all the items I added, since my comboboxes do show all the temperature names, but for some reason it doesn't compute based on what names are selected.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, trashgod. I will try that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should start of by making a `Actionlistener`. In this `ActionListener` object, you can make a lot of if's, which give you the result you search.

First of all your imports.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
```

Then make the frame.

```
public class StringAnswers extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 280);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Colored Animals");
        frame.setContentPane(new MyPanel());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
```

Your panel.

```
    class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        private JComboBox fromCombo, toCombo;
        private JButton convertBtn;
        private JLabel fromLabel, toLabel;
        private JTextField valueField;

        public MyPanel() {
            convertBtn = new JButton("OK");
            convertBtn.addActionListener(new ConvertHandler());
            add(convertBtn);

            fromLabel = new JLabel();
            add(fromLabel);
            toLabel = new JLabel();
            add(toLabel);

            valueField = new JTextField(10);
            add(valueField);
```

Make an array, to easily place it in a combobox. The layout.

```
            String[] entries = { "Celsius", "Fahrenheit", "Kelvin" };
            Font displayFont = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 21);

            fromCombo = new JComboBox(entries);
            fromCombo.setFont(displayFont);
            fromCombo.setVisible(true);
            add(fromCombo);
```

Second combobox.

```
            toCombo = new JComboBox(entries);
            toCombo.setFont(displayFont);
            toCombo.setVisible(true);
            add(toCombo);
        }
```

The buttonhandler. So when the button is pressed this action will happen.

```
        class ConvertHandler implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String temperature = (String) fromCombo.getSelectedItem();
                String convertTemp = (String) toCombo.getSelectedItem();
```

If in the first box Celsius is selected.

```
                if (temperature.equals("Celsius")) {
```

If in the second box Fahrenheit is selected.

```
                    if (convertTemp.equals("Fahrenheit")) {
```

Then this action will happen.

```
                        String valueStr = valuefield.getText();
                        fromLabel.setText(valueStr);
                        double value = Double.parseDouble(valueStr);
                        double conv = value * 1.8 + 32;
                        String convStr = Double.toString(conv);
                        toLabel.setText(convStr);
                    }
```

This goes on for a while for every possible combination.

```
                    if (convertTemp.equals("Kelvin")) {
                        String valueStr = valuefield.getText();
                        fromLabel.setText(valueStr);
                        double value = Double.parseDouble(valueStr);
                        double conv = value + 273;
                        String convStr = Double.toString(conv);
                        toLabel.setText(convStr);
                    }
                    if (convertTemp.equals("Celsius")) {
                        String valueStr = valuefield.getText();
                        fromLabel.setText(valueStr);
                        double value = Double.parseDouble(valueStr);
                        double conv = value;
                        String convStr = Double.toString(conv);
                        toLabel.setText(convStr);
                    }
                }
                if (temperature.equals("Fahrenheit")) {
                    if (convertTemp.equals("Fahrenheit")) {
                        String valueStr = valuefield.getText();
                        fromLabel.setText(valueStr);
                        double value = Double.parseDouble(valueStr);
                        double conv = value;
                        String convStr = Double.toString(conv);
                        toLabel.setText(convStr);
                    }
                    if (convertTemp.equals("Kelvin")) {
                        String valueStr = valuefield.getText();
                        fromLabel.setText(valueStr);
                        double value = Double.parseDouble(valueStr);
                        double conv = (value + 459.67) * 5/9;
                        String convStr = Double.toString(conv);
                        toLabel.setText(convStr);
                    }
                    if (convertTemp.equals("Celsius")) {
                        String valueStr = valuefield.getText();
                        fromLabel.setText(valueStr);
                        double value = Double.parseDouble(valueStr);
                        double conv = (value - 32) * 5/9;
                        String convStr = Double.toString(conv);
                        toLabel.setText(convStr);
                    }
                }
                if (temperature.equals("Kelvin")) {
                    if (convertTemp.equals("Fahrenheit")) {
                        String valueStr = valuefield.getText();
                        fromLabel.setText(valueStr);
                        double value = Double.parseDouble(valueStr);
                        double conv = (value * (9/5)) - 459.67;
                        String convStr = Double.toString(conv);
                        toLabel.setText(convStr);
                    }
                    if (convertTemp.equals("Kelvin")) {
                        String valueStr = valuefield.getText();
                        fromLabel.setText(valueStr);
                        double value = Double.parseDouble(valueStr);
                        double conv = value;
                        String convStr = Double.toString(conv);
                        toLabel.setText(convStr);
                    }
                    if (convertTemp.equals("Celsius")) {
                        String valueStr = valuefield.getText();
                        fromLabel.setText(valueStr);
                        double value = Double.parseDouble(valueStr);
                        double conv = value - 273;
                        String convStr = Double.toString(conv);
                        toLabel.setText(convStr);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have done this with a lot of if's, there are probably much shorter ways, but this is my way. I hope it was helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

TriggeredDuck's answer shows how to perform this.  However, I would like to propose a means of tackling the nested `if` statements.

Consider the following Enum:

```
public enum Temperature {
  CELSIUS("Celsius", 1, 0),
  FARENHEIT("Farenheit", 1.8, 32),
  KELVIN("Kelvin", 1, 273);

  private String label;
  private double multiplier;
  private double offset;

  private Temperature(String label, double multiplier, double offset) {
    this.label = label;
    this.multiplier = multiplier;
    this.offset = offset;
  }

  public static Temperature parse(String label) {
    for (Temperature temp : Temperature.values()) {
      if (temp.label.equals(label)) {
        return temp;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public double convert(double value, Temperature to) {
    return (((value - offset) / multiplier) * to.multiplier) + to.offset;
  }
}
```

You can then replace the entirety of the action listener with:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  Temperature from = Temperature.parse((String)fromCombo.getSelectedItem());
  Temperature to = Temperature.parse((String)toCombo.getSelectedItem());
  double value = Double.parseDouble(valueField.getText());
  fromLabel.setText(Double.toString(value));
  double converted = from.convert(value, to);
  toLabel.setText(Double.toString(converted));
}
```